# How to add a context menu to onclick event of list view item

Tags: android, listview

I am using a list view. I use Efficient adapter to add the items. I am using alert dialog for onclick event of each row. But it gives me just two options. I want more options, so I wish to context menu on long press on each row of list view. Here is my code:

```
    public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);              


             convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    private int pos=position;

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                           

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(curr_inst);


                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Data selection");                              
                        alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Do you wish to capture new data or access already stored data?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Capture new data",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    Bundle b=new Bundle();
                                    String array = DATA[pos];
                                    b.putString("user",array);                                      
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(curr_inst, BluetoothConnect.class);
                                    intent.putExtras(b);            

                                    curr_inst.startActivity(intent);


                                }
                              })
                            .setNegativeButton("Access stored data",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    Bundle b=new Bundle();
                                    //String[] name={ "adi","MEGAN","DAVE","JOHN","HENDRIX"};
                                    String array = DATA[pos];
                                    b.putString("key",array); 
                                    Intent i =new Intent(curr_inst,List13.class);
                                    i.putExtras(b);     

                                    curr_inst.startActivity(i)  ;                               
                                }
                            });

                            // create alert dialog
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();     
                            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

                    }
                });
            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
```

I want to use a context menu in place of this alert dialog box, can anyone tell me how to do it. I tried using `registerForContextMenu(convertView);`but, it says cannot make a static reference to the non-static method registerForContextMenu(View) from the type Activity

Updated code:

```
    public class List14 extends ListActivity {
//; 
static List14 curr_inst;
boolean FirstUSe1 = false;
boolean FirstUSe2 = true;
int count = 1; 

public int counter() {
    return DATA.length;
}

public static void update()
{
    EfficientAdapter k=new EfficientAdapter(curr_inst);
    //convertView.setTag(holder);
    k.notifyDataSetChanged();       
    curr_inst.setListAdapter(k);
}

private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    /**
     * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of speeches
     * in our array.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return DATA.length;
    }

    /**
     * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
     * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
     * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
     * list.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Use the array index as a unique id.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Make a view to hold each row.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
     *      android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        final ViewHolder holder;
        pos = position;

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);              

             convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v1){
                     pos = position;
                     curr_inst.registerForContextMenu(v1);
                    }                      
            });
            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);             

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
             convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                     
                     public void onClick(View v2){
                         pos=position;
                         curr_inst.registerForContextMenu(v2);
                        }
                   });
            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);             
            }

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
        holder.text1.setText(DATA_NAME[position]);
        holder.text2.setText(DATA_AGE[position]);
        //holder.del.setImageBitmap(mIcon3);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;          
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;             
    }
    }
```

Comment: does your context menu change its items based on the row being clicked?

Comment: No the items are the same for each row, but their onlcik events depend on the corresponding row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is, but I tried it the following way and it didn't show up any error to me.

Try this,

```
if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_element, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                      m_Activity.registerForContextMenu(v);

                }
            });
         }
```

Here **m_Activity** is a Activity Object. Please note the Context object will not work in this case. You need to pass your Activity object to do this.

Comment: Hey, this is working fine. But I want to pass the position of my list item to the context menu. Can you tell me how to do that.

Comment: i am not sure if that's doable. But you can store the position globally and use it in some manner I guess.

Comment: Hey Andro, there seems to be some problem with the code. The position that I declare globally is not updated every time I click on list item. I have posted the updated code.

Comment: or you can use the LIstView's itemClicklistener. It will return the correct position. YOu can use it from there. It should be reliable.

Comment: Can you tell me where should I use it? I am using a listACtivity, I dont have any listview

Comment: just click ctrl+space in your activity and from the list look for method that starts like onItemclick...

Comment: Hi included  `public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id)
     {
      pos = position;  
   registerForContextMenu(view);
     }`
But nothing happened. It gives the same result.

Comment: did u remove the pos updating from the getView?

Comment: Yes I removed it from there.

Comment: Did u put a log to check if the code reaches item click listener correctly?

Comment: I debugged it.. It reached there initially.. and updates it. But when I click on other item, it doesnt go inside on item click Listener and the position is not updated.

Comment: The problem is with context menu. When i removed registerForContextMenu(view), the position is getting updated everytime i click.

Comment: oh i think you should register it only once but instead call openContextmenu() each time!!

Comment: do you mean this:
`@Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id)
     {
   int item_pos= (Integer) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
      Toast.makeText(this, item_pos + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      if (!FirstUSe1)
      {
      curr_inst.registerForContextMenu(view);
      FirstUSe1 = true;
      }
      else
      curr_inst.openContextMenu(view);
    }`

Comment: yes something like that. If it doesn't work for you I am really out of ideas. sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
     public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            item_pos= (Integer) getListAdapter().getItem(position);     
            registerForContextMenu(l);
            openContextMenu(l);//           
          }
```

The above code works. Previously i was using view in place of listview. Now it works perfectly.